# Windows software to swap stereo channels in real time

Tags: audio, windows-10

I am looking for a program for Windows 10 that will read stereo sound from given input device, swap left and right channels, then write to the given output device in real time (possibly with small delay, no more than 50ms). Preferably free software or freeware.

P.S. Please do not reply "just move the speakers" or similar, as I want to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Equalizer APO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/) might be what you're looking for.

After downloading and installing (and restarting Windows), however, it will take a bit of configuration to achieve what you need:

1. On first start, it will ask you to configure the output devices. Select your main output device, usually `Speakers - VIA HD Audio` or `Speakers - Realtek HD Audio` or something like that.
2. In the Equalizer APO Configuration Editor, click the red minus icons next to each of the active filter items to remove them all.
3. Click the green plus icon, select `Basic filters`, `Copy (Copy between channels)`
4. Drag the red `L` over to the green `R` below it, which will create an arrow pointing diagonally from one to the other. Repeat the same for the other side, dragging the red `R` over the green `L`.

If the power icon for that configuration is white, it means your stereo has been swapped. If it's black, it's off. Run some tests to verify this.

This is a simplified, GUI version of the [manual configuration task, originally suggested at Seven Forums](https://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/153182-swap-left-right-audio-channels.html).

Comment: Thank you, this is BY FAR the simplest method (which is crazy considering you have to use APO installer to overwrite C: Drive).
Also your instructions are the most effective and simple to follow other sites had at least twice as many steps and none to clear.

Comment: @user45029 Thank you! I really enjoy writing documentation and tutorials! :-)